Cant figure out trunks on ASR9K IOS-XR
I can't figure out how to migrate 3 trunks from a cisco 7609 running IOS to an ASR9K running IOS-XR.
Basically all three trunks have common vlans that need to talk.
7609 Config:
int te1/1
switchport mode trunk 
switchport trunk allowed vlan 10

int te1/2
switchport mode trunk 
switchport trunk allowed vlan 10, 20

int te1/3
switchport mode trunk 
switchport trunk allowed vlan 10, 20


I simply need the three trunks to be in the same broadcast domain. I tried the following config on the ASR but had no luck. For context the L3 for VL10 is on the other side of te1/2 at a remote site. VL10 hosts could then be on te1/1 or te1/3.

interface te1/1
interface te1/1.10 l2transport
interface te1/1.10 l2transport encapsulation dot1q 10  
interface te1/1.10 l2transport rewrite ingress tag pop 1 symmetric  
interface te1/2
interface te1/2.10 l2transport
interface te1/2.10 l2transport encapsulation dot1q 10  
interface te1/2.10 l2transport rewrite ingress tag pop 1 symmetric  
interface te1/2.20 l2transport
interface te1/2.20 l2transport encapsulation dot1q 20  
interface te1/2.20 l2transport rewrite ingress tag pop 1 symmetric  
interface te1/3
interface te1/3.10 l2transport
interface te1/3.10 l2transport encapsulation dot1q 10  
interface te1/3.10 l2transport rewrite ingress tag pop 1 symmetric  
interface te1/3.20 l2transport
interface te1/3.20 l2transport encapsulation dot1q 20  
interface te1/3.20 l2transport rewrite ingress tag pop 1 symmetric  

l2vpn bridge group group1
l2vpn bridge group group1 bridge-domain vlan10
l2vpn bridge group group1 bridge-domain vlan10 interface te1/1.10
l2vpn bridge group group1 bridge-domain vlan10 interface te1/1.10 split-horizon group  
l2vpn bridge group group1 bridge-domain vlan10 interface te1/2.10
l2vpn bridge group group1 bridge-domain vlan10 interface te1/2.10 split-horizon group  
l2vpn bridge group group1 bridge-domain vlan10 interface te1/3.10
l2vpn bridge group group1 bridge-domain vlan10 interface te1/3.10 split-horizon group  

l2vpn bridge group group2
l2vpn bridge group group2 bridge-domain vlan20
l2vpn bridge group group2 bridge-domain vlan20 interface te1/2.20
l2vpn bridge group group2 bridge-domain vlan20 interface te1/2.20 split-horizon group  
l2vpn bridge group group2 bridge-domain vlan20 interface te1/3.20
l2vpn bridge group group2 bridge-domain vlan20 interface te1/3.20 split-horizon group  




Im simplifying the number of vlans for the sake of the example. The actual number of common vlans is closer to 100. Would it be possible to set this up similar to "switchport trunk allowed vlan all" that way I wouldnt have to build out each individual vlan?
Not sure what Im missing here since my example looks like it would work.
Any help would be much appreciated.
